# making redux actions async on multiple onClicks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

In my Application I have two panels, I load the information of one panel based on the other panel click event (in short fetch post by Id). If I click post-B dispatching an action send api-request and fetch data works fine, but when the current api call is stil loading now I click on post-A another api-request is sent. If the post-B api call data is large it takes bit time before that the post-A api request loads and updates the state and then the first api call data is updated the state is inconsistent.

for eg :
post A ---- post B data is shown

I don't know this happens only when the api call takes time to load the data or when I click multiple post at fast pace randomly I don't get the relevant information in the second panel to respective post I clicked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspense-forked-r4g33?file=/src/TvShowDetails.js
This is what am trying to achieve with redux.

Comment: I don't see any redux code, so I am assuming you are thinking of moving to redux and you want to know if that will solve your current problem. If so, then you can take a look at 
`redux-saga` library that is used for async operations like data fetching. Check `takeLatest` effect creator.

Comment: @FahadFarooq is there any equivalent to `takeLatest` in redux-thunk.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple.
Just use saga take latest.
And use one parameter in store reducer to get override with each api response.
Click on post -> call api with id -> get response -> store it to reducer.
If you clicked multiple times on same post or clicked some other post simultaneously. The take latest will take the latest click that you have made. Since you are using one store parameter, the data also will get override.
If the api call is take more time, I would recommend to show loader till get the response for the last/latest api call.